Issue with NuGet Pre-Release Versioning in CI/CD Pipeline with +semver: major
I'm encountering an issue with the pre-release versioning of NuGet packages in our CI/CD pipeline. The standard NuGet package versions are working correctly, but there's a problem when creating pre-release versions during pull requests (PRs), even when using +semver: major in the commit messages.
Context:

Current version before PR: 5.1.1
Commit message includes: +semver: major
Expected pre-release version format during PRs:
6.0.0-pullrequestxxxxx
Actual pre-release version being generated: 5.1.2-pullrequestxxxxx

Recent Changes:
This issue started occurring after we upgraded from gitversion/setup@0 to gitversion/setup@1. The previous GitVersion configuration was:

task: gitversion/execute@1
name: Execute

The updated configuration is:

checkout: self
fetchDepth: 0
task: gitversion/setup@1
displayName: 'Install GitVersion'
inputs:
versionSpec: '5.x'
preferLatestVersion: true
task: gitversion/execute@1
name: Execute

Reason for the change:
Azure DevOps Pipeline Error: No Agent Found with Version Greater Than 2.220.0
Issue:
When we create a PR, the build system is generating a pre-release NuGet package version like 5.1.2-pullrequestxxxxx instead of the expected 6.0.0-pullrequestxxxxx, despite using +semver: major in the commit messages. However, after the PR is approved and merged, the released version correctly updates to 6.0.0.
Question:
How can I ensure that the pre-release NuGet package versions correctly reflect the major version change during the PR process, especially when using +semver: major in the commit messages? Is there a specific configuration or step in the CI/CD pipeline that I might be missing or need to adjust?
Any insights or suggestions on how to address this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
gitversion.yml
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

parameters:
- name: tagSources
  displayName: Tag Sources
  type: boolean
  default: false
- name: configFilePath
  type: string
  displayName: 'GitVersion Configuration Path.'
  default: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)\GitVersion.yml'

steps:
- powershell: | 
    Write-Host "Original Build Number: $env:Build_BuildNumber"
  name: LogOriginalBuildNumber
  displayName: Log Original Build Number
- powershell: |
    $env:GitVersionConfigExists = Test-Path $env:GitVersionConfigurationPath
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=GitVersionConfigExists]$env:GitVersionConfigExists"
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=GitVersionConfigExists;isOutput=true]$env:GitVersionConfigExists"
  name: DetectGitVersionConfig
  displayName: Detect '${{ parameters.configFilePath }}'
  env:
    GitVersionConfigurationPath: ${{ parameters.configFilePath }}
- checkout: self
  fetchDepth: 0
- task: gitversion/setup@1
  displayName: 'Install GitVersion'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '5.x'
    preferLatestVersion: true    
- task: gitversion/execute@1
  name: Execute
  inputs:
    useConfigFile: $(DetectGitVersionConfig.GitVersionConfigExists)
    configFilePath: ${{ parameters.configFilePath }}
  displayName: Execute GitVersion
- ${{ if parameters.tagSources }}:
  - powershell: |
      #region Text Utils
      function ConvertTo-PowershellLiteral {
        [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'WithoutBuilder')]
        Param(
          [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'WithBuilder', Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
          [System.Text.StringBuilder]$Builder,
          [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'WithBuilder', Position = 0,ValueFromRemainingArguments)]
          [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'WithoutBuilder', ValueFromPipeline, Position = 0,ValueFromRemainingArguments)]
          [object[]]$Value
        )
        Begin {
          $ExternalBuilder = $PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'WithBuilder'
          if (-not $ExternalBuilder) {
            $Builder = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new()
          }
      
          function ConvertTo-DoubleLiteral([Parameter(Position = 0)][double]$Value) { if ([double]::IsNaN($Value)) { '[double]::NaN' }  elseif([double]::IsPositiveInfinity($Value)) { '[double]::PositiveInfinity' } elseif([double]::IsNegativeInfinity(($Value))) { '[double]::NegativeInfinity' } elseif($Value -eq [double]::Epsilon) { '[double]::Epsilon' } elseif($Value -eq [double]::MaxValue) { '[double]::MaxValue' } elseif($Value -eq [double]::MinValue) { '[double]::MinValue' } else { $Value.ToString('G17', [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture) } }
          function ConvertTo-SingleLiteral([Parameter(Position = 0)][float]$Value) { if ([float]::IsNaN($Value)) { '[float]::NaN' }  elseif([float]::IsPositiveInfinity($Value)) { '[float]::PositiveInfinity' } elseif([float]::IsNegativeInfinity(($Value))) { '[float]::NegativeInfinity' } elseif($Value -eq [float]::Epsilon) { '[float]::Epsilon' } elseif($Value -eq [float]::MaxValue) { '[float]::MaxValue' } elseif($Value -eq [float]::MinValue) { '[float]::MinValue' } else { $Value.ToString('G17', [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture) } }
          function ProcessItem([Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)][System.Text.StringBuilder]$Builder, [Parameter(Position = 0)]$Value, [switch]$ForceQuotes = $false) {
            if ($Value -isnot [string] -and $Value -is [System.Collections.IEnumerable]) {
              $AppendedValueItem = $false
              $Builder.Append('@(') | Out-Null
              foreach ($ValueItem in $Value) {
                if ($AppendedValueItem) { $Builder.Append(', ') | Out-Null}
                ProcessItem -Builder $Builder -Value $ValueItem
                $AppendedValueItem = $true
              }
              $Builder.Append(')')
            }
            else {
              switch ($Value) {
                $null { $Builder.Append('$null');break }
                { $_ -is [string] } {
                  if ($ForceQuotes -or $_ -match '[\s''"]') {
                    $Start = $Builder.Append([char]'''').Length
                    $Builder.Append($_).Replace('''', '''''', $Start, $Builder.Length - $Start).Append([char]'''')
                  }
                  else {
                    $Builder.Append($_)
                  }
                  break
                }
                { $_ -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] } { ($Builder.Append('[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]::new(') | ProcessItem -Value $_.FullName -ForceQuotes).Append(')');break     }
                { $_ -is [System.IO.FileInfo] } { ($Builder.Append('[System.IO.FileInfo]::new(') | ProcessItem -Value $_.FullName -ForceQuotes).Append(')');break }
                { $_ -is [double] } { $Builder.Append((ConvertTo-DoubleLiteral $_));break }
                { $_ -is [float] } { $Builder.Append((ConvertTo-SingleLiteral $_));break }
                { $_ -is [byte] -or $_ -is [sbyte] -or $_ -is [uint16] -or $_ -is [int16] -or $_ -is [uint32] -or $_ -is [int] -or $_ -is [uint64] -or $_ -is [long] } { $Builder.Append($_.ToString([System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture));break }
                Default { throw "Unexpected value type: $($_.GetType().FullName)"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        Process {
          if ($Value) {
            $AppendedAny = $false
            foreach ($Item in $Value) {
              if ($AppendedAny) { 
                $Builder.Append([char]' ') | Out-Null
              }
              ProcessItem -Builder $Builder -Value $Item | Out-Null
              $AppendedAny = $true
            }
          }
          if ($ExternalBuilder) {
            $Builder
          }
          else {
            $Builder.ToString()
            $Builder.Clear() | Out-Null
          }
        }
      }
      #endregion
      #region Logging Comands
      function Write-PipelineCommand([Parameter(Position = 0, ValueFromRemainingArguments)][string[]]$Command) {
        Process {
          Write-Host -Object (([System.Text.StringBuilder]::new('##[command]') | ConvertTo-PowershellLiteral -Value $Command).ToString())
        }
      }
      #endregion
      Write-PipelineCommand git tag --force "v$($env:GitVersion_FullSemVer)" $env:GitVersion_Sha
      git tag --force "v$($env:GitVersion_FullSemVer)" $env:GitVersion_Sha
      Write-PipelineCommand git '-c' http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer ***" push --force origin refs/tags/v$($env:GitVersion_FullSemVer)
      git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION`: bearer $env:System_AccessToken" push --force origin refs/tags/v$($env:GitVersion_FullSemVer)
    name: TagSources
    displayName: Tag Sources
    condition: eq(variables['GitVersion.PreReleaseTagWithDash'], '') # Cannot use `PreReleaseTag` as it is the `UncommittedChanges` when there isn't a pre-release tag.
    env:
      System_AccessToken: $(System.AccessToken)

$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)\GitVersion.yml
assembly-versioning-scheme: MajorMinorPatch
mode: Mainline
branches: {}
ignore:
  sha: []
merge-message-formats: {}

Modified the gitversion.yml as per the suggestion.
$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)\GitVersion.yml
assembly-versioning-scheme: MajorMinorPatch
mode: Mainline
branches: {}
ignore:
  sha: []
merge-message-formats: {}
tag-prefix: '[vV]?'
assembly-informational-format: '{Major}.{Minor}.{Patch}'
major-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(breaking|major)'
minor-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(feature|minor)'
patch-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(fix|patch)'
no-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(none|skip)'
commit-message-incrementing: Enabled
update-build-number: true

The pre-release versions are still not incrementing as expected. We expect a version like 8.2.0-PullRequestxxxxx, but instead, the patch version is being incremented, even though we are adding +semver: minor in the commit message.

Note: pre-release version was worked fine with these yml before changing it to use setup@1

Can you post the detailed of your GitVersion.yml file so that we can know how you configure to generate the version numbers?

@BrightRan-MSFT please check my update.

The first content you provided is the details of the pipeline YAML not GitVersion.yml file. The second YAML content looks is from the GitVersion.yml file but does it the completely detailed content of the file? @Dinesh

@BrightRan-MSFT Yes, you are correct. The second yml is the full content.

I configure the GitVersion.yml file like as below, and it can increment the major version as expected when I add "+semver: major" into the commit message.

Sample of GitVersion.yml.

# GitVersion.yml

mode: mainline
tag-prefix: '[vV]?'
assembly-informational-format: '{Major}.{Minor}.{Patch}'
major-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(breaking|major)'
minor-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(feature|minor)'
patch-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(fix|patch)'
no-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(none|skip)'
commit-message-incrementing: Enabled
update-build-number: true


Sample of azure-pipelines.yml.

# azure-pipelines.yml

jobs:
- job: build
  steps:
  - checkout: self
    fetchDepth: 0
  
  - task: gitversion/setup@1
    displayName: 'Install GitVersion'
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '5.x'
      preferLatestVersion: true
  
  - task: gitversion/execute@1
    displayName: 'Generate Version'
  
  - bash: |
      echo "GitVersion.FullSemVer = $(GitVersion.FullSemVer)"
      echo "GitVersion.SemVer = $(GitVersion.SemVer)"
    displayName: 'View Version'




I believe these versions were made after you merged the changes to the main branch. What about the version number for pre-release?

@Dinesh, when the pipeline is triggered by PR, it also can generated the version number, and you can add a step to combine the generated version number with the suffix "-pullrequestxxxxx" to get the pre-release version.
